# Broken packages issue on 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Supermicro server. While installing `chrony`, I got the message below:

```
root@xxx:~# apt-get install chrony
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 chrony : Depends: libtomcrypt0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tried running `apt-get install -f` but it did not solve the issue:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Ran `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`, but it gave no results.

Ran `dpkg --configure -a` but after that I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you look online for the "libtomcrypt0" .deb file for Ubuntu 16.04? You can install that with dpkg.

Comment: It is not only for the mentioned package but other packages as well                          sudo apt-get install -f rdesktop
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rdesktop : Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)
            Depends: libpcsclite1 (>= 1.3.0) but it is not installable
            Depends: libxrandr2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.